# Error when sending email with Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()

Tags: email, meteor, smtp, meteor-accounts

Thank you for reading my message, here is my problem :
I recently started using email package, I defined `MAIL_URL` and sent emails with `Email.send()` successfully.
But now I want to send verification emails and I got errors. Here is my code :

### On server

```
Meteor.methods({
    'sendVerificationEmail'(){
        Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(Meteor.userId());
    }
});
```

### On client

```
Meteor.call('sendVerificationEmail');
```

I got the following error :
[image]
With a few research I found this :

> This message means that the email you sent was blocked by the
>   recipient's email hosting server, and returned to you

I tried `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()` with users who have different emails (gmail, disposable email, email of my personal website) and I always have the same error.
The strange thing is that `Email.send()` works perfectly...

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT :**
The email address I'm using to send those emails is using the domain rezarahemtola.com
Here is the result of `dig rezarahemtola.com ns` that Scott Stensland asked me to run in his answer :
[image]

Comment: Do you use the default verification message or did you customize it

Comment: @Jankapunkt I'm using the default one as shown here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution for anyone facing the same problem :

As I said `Email.send()` was working correctly but got an error with `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail`, `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` etc.

Looks like Meteor can't retrieve automatically the sender address when using those methods, so you should set it like that :

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "Your_Name <your_email@example.com>";
```

You can also [check the docs about it](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-emailTemplates).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the dns hosting provider for your domain name ... like example.com ... assure you have added an `MX`  Record Type ... it typically uses a value as

```
10  example.com
```

you can get a hint as to where your dns hosting is by issuing

```
dig  example.com  ns
```

to display its Name Server  (  ns  )

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what are you asking me to do... I'm using an email from my domain rezarahemtola.com to send emails, so I executed `dig rezarahemtola.com ns` and I updated my question with the result. As I said I can succesfully send emails with `Email.send()`, the problem occurs while using `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()`